# How to pass options to latex compiler using rubber?

Tags: compiling, rubber

Gedit with latex plugin is a great tool for working with latex. However I need to modify standard tool which is is just a call of rubber. I would like to have possibility to to use inverse search. To this end I need to pass `-src` option to latex compiler and I do not know if it is possible with rubber.

Answer (score 5):

From a [rubber's launchpad bug site](https://bugs.launchpad.net/rubber/+bug/801276):

> Actually, there is already a way to do that, although I admit it is
>   not very well documented. From the command line, you can do
>
> ```
> $ rubber -c 'setlist arguments --shell-escape' -d foo.tex
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can make this automatic in your document by
>   including a comment line that says
>
> ```
> % rubber: setlist arguments --shell-escape
> ```
>
> As you can guess, this "arguments" variable can be used to pass
>   arbitrary arguments to the compiler. The complete list of such
>   variables and directives is in the info documentation.

Comment: I get `CallArity-TFP.tex_lhs:2: unknown directive 'setlist'` – any ideas?

Comment: According to the manual, accesible with `info rubber`, you should type `% rubber: set arguments -shell-escape`.

Comment: Apparently newer versions (I have 1.1) don't support `setlist` anymore, `info rubber` says one should just use `set`, like this: `% rubber: set arguments --shell-escape`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following kludge. In my case I wanted to always pass certain additional options to bibtex. Therefore I created the following script and saved it as `~/bin/bibtex`:

```
#! /bin/sh
exec /usr/texbin/bibtex -min-crossrefs=999 "$@"
```

Then I made sure that `~/bin` is in my `PATH` before `/usr/texbin`. That's all. Now rubber (and all other tools that invoke `bibtex`) have the right parameters set.